# Problema com comparações no batch

Tags: cmd, batch

Boa tarde. Eu estava fazendo um arquivo simples de batch, em geral, um amigo meu precisava que eu fizesse aquele enigma dos 3 galões de água em batch (Dos galões de 8, 5 e 3 litros) Em geral a lógica do batch é muito simples, porém ele está com um problema na comparação, onde há a linha:

```
set /A VARIAVELVASO3NO1=%CONTEUDOVASO3%-%QUANTIDADELIVREVASO1%+10
if "%VARIAVELVASO3NO1%" GEQ "10" (
    set/a CONTEUDOVASO3=%CONTEUDOVASO3%-%QUANTIDADELIVREVASO1%
    set/a CONTEUDOVASO1=8
    goto JOGOVASOS
) ELSE (
    set/a CONTEUDOVASO1=%CONTEUDOVASO3%+%CONTEUDOVASO1%
    set/a CONTEUDOVASO3=0
    goto JOGOVASOS
)
```

O valor que %VARIAVELVASO3NO1% fica é 8, já que o %CONTEUDOVASO3% é igual a 3; e %QUANTIDADELIVREVASO1% é igual a 5 (3-5+10=8). Porém, ao invés de entrar no estado FALSO (que seria o ELSE) ele entra no primeiro, que é o estado VERDADEIRO, eu primeiro achei que era um problema com números negativos, então coloquei tudo acima de 10 (por isso o +10 na fórmula) mas mesmo assim o problema persiste, alguma ideia do que pode ser?

Comment: Já tentou sem as aspas? if %VARIAVELVASO3NO1% GEQ 10 (

Comment: Era só isso, eu não acredito que eu passei 1 hora tentando resolver o problema de duas aspas, muito obrigado cara!

Comment: Pode aceitar a resposta abaixo então? Valeu!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remova as aspas:

```
if %VARIAVELVASO3NO1% GEQ 10 (
    set/a CONTEUDOVASO3=%CONTEUDOVASO3%-%QUANTIDADELIVREVASO1%
    set/a CONTEUDOVASO1=8
    goto JOGOVASOS
)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Darius da costa, recomendo sempre fazer comparações **sem aspas**
>
> só faça comparações com aspas quando for fazer comparações de strings com
> várias palavras.
>
> e faça da seguinte maneira:

```
    if "%string1%" equ "%string2" (Echo.São iguais) Else (
    Echo.Não são iguais
    )
```

> fica a dica.

Comment: Sim, eu já havia percebido o erro, muito obrigado!